# Display data from controller into view as column and row

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

[image: detail_konten data]I'm using laravel 5.5 and i have some array of data. How to display it into view, but i want to diplay every record of data into column.

Here's my controller

```
$cari_pengecekan = Pengecekan::whereYear('waktu_cek', $tahun)->whereMonth('waktu_cek', $bulan)->where('id_form_ceklis', $form_id)->orderBy('waktu_cek', 'asc')->get();
        foreach($cari_pengecekan as $pengecekan){
            $detail_pengecekan = Detail_Pengecekan::where('id_pengecekan', $pengecekan->id_pengecekan)->orderBy('id_konten_ceklis', 'asc')->get();
            foreach($detail_pengecekan as $detail){
                $detail_konten[] = $detail; 
            }
        }
```

[image: Tables view that i want to make]

Thanks for helping

Comment: What do you want to do

Comment: @su3158 I think OP wants to transpose

Comment: @richyen Is it okay to line up the contents in foreach?

Comment: @su3158 yeah that's what I'm wondering.  What is the var that gets printed out on that screenshot?

Comment: @maulana-lutfi which var gets printed to screenshot? is it `$detail_konten`?

Comment: the var is detail_konten

Comment: Does it look like an associative array?
Is it just turning two arrays?

Comment: it just turning an array

Comment: So you want to print  $detail_konten[]  data into view in column and row ?

Comment: Semangat yaa gan

Comment: yeah, i want to print $detail_konten[] into view

Comment: Hi, for nice tables i will recomend you datatable. Here is great support for Larvel: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables It very easy to implement, you can make serwer side tables with a lot of data and add some filtering and sorting - great stuff :)